# Increasing the height of concrete

Tags: concrete

There is an expansion joint roughly 1 foot from the front edge of the garage that runs parallel to the garage and that 2 inch rise into the garage.  One end of the 1 foot section is lower than the driveway. is there a way to increase the height without using a jackhammer. I need 1/2 to 3/4 inches.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture or two would really help us understand your question better.

Answer (score 1):

You  can do mud jacking, or poly jacking underneath the low side - it will raise it a little might cost you about $1K could be less but I doubt it. You can call for a free estimate from a local contractor. Maybe they only charge you $500.

Comment: Ken is referring to the process of drilling a hole through the slab and pumping a cement slurry in to lift the slab. It requires special equipment but can be very effective.